# Google Jam 2008 Qualification Round: B - Train Timetable

Tags: algorithm

[Here's a problem](https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/32013/dashboard#s=p1).

I don't understand the problem itself before solving it.
Specifically: **whenever a train is supposed to leave A or B, there must actually be one there ready to go**. What does it look like? Can you give me examples? Thanks.

**Problem**

A train line has two stations on it, A and B. Trains can take trips from A to B or from B to A multiple times during a day. When a train arrives at B from A (or arrives at A from B), it needs a certain amount of time before it is ready to take the return journey - this is the turnaround time. For example, if a train arrives at 12:00 and the turnaround time is 0 minutes, it can leave immediately, at 12:00.

A train timetable specifies departure and arrival time of all trips between A and B. The train company needs to know how many trains have to start the day at A and B in order to make the timetable work: whenever a train is supposed to leave A or B, there must actually be one there ready to go. There are passing sections on the track, so trains don't necessarily arrive in the same order that they leave. Trains may not travel on trips that do not appear on the schedule.

Comment: the link leads to another problem

Comment: Thanks Andy. Fixed the URL.

Answer (score 2):

> I don't understand the problem itself before solving it. Specifically:
>   whenever a train is supposed to leave A or B, there must actually be
>   one there ready to go. What does it look like? Can you give me
>   examples? Thanks.

It simply means that you have to ensure that the time-table is respected. That is there should be atleast one train ready to leave the particular station at the scheduled time as per the time-table.

For example, if the timetable for A to B is:

```
 09:00 12:00
 10:00 13:00
 11:00 12:30
```

Then you have to ensure that at least one train is available and ready to leave station A at times `09:00, 10:00 and 11:00`.

Comment: Now I see. The goal is to find the minimum number of trains to respect this timetable.